# Symfony : Custom validator never called

Tags: symfony, validation

In Symfony (& easyadmin), I would like to validate, using a custom function, some of the edit/new form fields on submission.

I then tought creating a custom validator, but it is never called.
Here are the created files. What did I miss?

```
config/validator/validation.yaml

App\Entity\ClassePrice:
    constraints:
        - App\Validator\Constraints\StepsCoverage: ~



src/Validator/Constraints/StepsCoverage.php

<?php
namespace App\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class StepsCoverage extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'The steps coverage is not valid';

    public function getTargets()
    {
        return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }
}

src/Validator/Constraints/StepsCoverageValidator.php


<?php
namespace App\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedValueException;

class StepsCoverageValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($prices, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $toto=1;

    }
}
```

A breakpoint on $toto=1 never reached...

Thank you for your help,

Comment: show me where do you add this constraint

Comment: Your config and classes are ok. Are you sure validate function is not called? Rebuild cache may be an option. Check your framework config too ... https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#configuration validation must be enabled.